# can not use log.info() method under @Test methods while using @slf4j

Tags: logging, automation, slf4j

I have added following on my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
   <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
   <version>1.18.12</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And added @Slf4j annotation just before the class.
Now I want to use log.info() method under my class with @Test annotation within the same class.

But I don't get the log. to use.

Need help for this.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following on my project and found the issue as fixed. Hope this would help others, who are the beginners.

1. In the pom.xml file, add the following dependencies:

   ```
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
           <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
           <version>1.18.12</version>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>


      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
           <version>1.7.30</version>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
   ```
2. Go to your project> settings> search for 'annotations' > under Build > enable annotation> make sure the checkbox is enabled.
3. Then, go to settings > plugins > search for 'lombok' on the marketplace> install 'lombok' > restart intelliJ IDEA.

Then you should be able to start slf4j logging functionalities.